# The node version is different when I ssh into an instance than when I do it manually

Tags: node.js, linux, ssh, google-compute-engine

it would be amazing if you could help me with this.

When I run `node -v` manually on a GCE instance, it indicates that the node version is `v12.18.3`
But when I run it with this other command from the Cloud Shell:

```
gcloud compute ssh [USER]@[GCE instance] --zone [ZONE] --project [PROJECT ID] --command "node -v"
```

It indicates that the node version is `v14.17.1`

Why is this happening? How can I make it to the `v12.18.3` version ? I need it because my Vue application will not work properly with the version 14 of node.

**Extra information:**

```
nvm ls
       v12.18.0
->     v12.18.3
         system
default -> 12.18.0 (-> v12.18.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v12.18.3) (default)
stable -> 12.18 (-> v12.18.3) (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.1 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.17.1 (-> N/A)
```

- My npm version is 6.14.6
- My nvm version is 0.38.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is likely more than one version of that binary present on the host, and depending where you execute the command from, the PATH might be set differently which in turn selects a a different binary to run.

You can run `which -a node` on the host to find all versions of that binary, and then run them with the full path i.e `/usr/local/bin/node -v` to find out which one is being loaded under which conditions.

After that I believe you can remove the offending one or change the PATH variable to load the correct one.

Comment: I removed the incorrect content in PATH and I also had to run this
sudo ln -s //home/[MYUSER]/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
to add it in usr/local as it wasn't there.
And now it's working, thanks Stephan!

Comment: @ikerlasaga I know this is old but would you be able to elaborate/provide the steps you went through. I am using NVM and I find myself with two paths /usr/bin/node and /bin/node after running which -a node. I am also not sure what is meant by removing the incorrect content in PATH.